# Session variable is set, but PHP reporting it is not set?

Tags: php, session, variables, isset

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

gives me this:

```
[post] =>
[verify] => 3bae5359ea60d7f00d553ae5d091ae4b
[token] =>
```

token is set, but null, right? When I implement this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    die("Token not set");
}
```

The script dies. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) -

> bool isset ( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )
>
> isset determines if a variable is set and is not NULL

Also -

> Return Values: Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than
> NULL, FALSE otherwise.

So, if the supplied argument contains NULL or if it simply doesn't exist, then `isset` will return `FALSE`. This is exactly what is happening with your script and as a result, it dies.

Answer (score 1):

There is no value in $_SESSION['token'] that's why it is falling in if condition and dies.